# Getting R Selenium to Run on internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, rselenium

I am trying to run `RSelenium` with internet explorer
I have downloaded the jar file `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1` which according to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-saucelabs.html) has internet explorer already available to it

My Code is below and it connects to the server without issue
My only concern is it seems to connect as `firefox` which wont work for us as internally our systems seem to only function with IE

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "internet explorer")
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4444)
remDr$open()
```

Do i need to install something else?

I have created a batchfile to run like below before the script starts

```
chdir /d C:\Selenium\
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

Comment: You will need to download the IEDriverServer see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver . Take special note of the Required Configuration section.

Comment: I have a project in beta which may help if you want to email me at address given in https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/blob/master/DESCRIPTION